# Multiple True conditions in an IF statement in VB

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to have multiple conditions that can evaluate to true in an if statement? Primarily just shorthand to save some time:

Example:

```
if value = 1 or value = 9 or value = 3 or value = 17 Then return True
```

Im wondering if there is something to this effect (could not find in MSDN)

```
if value = 1,9,3,17 Then return True
```

Comment: All great tips. I always forget about many of the ways to shorten up code. Need a cheat sheet or similar of the most common ones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do that with an IF statement, but you could use:

```
SELECT CASE value
    CASE 1, 3, 9, 17
        ' Do something
    CASE 2, 4
        ' Do another thing
    CASE ELSE
        ' Do something else
END SELECT
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a return statement, you could make it bit shorter like this;

```
Return value = 1 Or value = 9 Or value = 3 Or value = 17
```

Also if the values would be in an array, you could use Linq - Any function;

```
Dim value As Integer = 1
Dim values = New Integer() {1, 9, 3, 17}
Return values.Any(Function(number) number = value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try like:

```
If (New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}).Contains(value)) Then
    Return TRUE
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want exactly within VB, but you can get around it. Here is one method. Put your values into an `Array`. You can search the `Array` using the `IndexOf` method. If the [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a number above -1, then the item was found in the array. There are some gotchas that you will want to read about on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim value As Boolean
Dim myList() As Integer = {1, 9, 3, 17}
If Array.IndexOf(myList, 12) > -1 Then
    value = True
Else
    value = False
End If

Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", value)
```

You can also shorten the test to an inline comparison and assignment, removing the need for the `If` statement above.:

```
value = (Array.IndexOf(myList, 12) > -1)
```